# left outer join em uma cláusula or

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou com um problema com uma consulta, que preciso fazer um left outer join de uma tabela com outra, ou considerando os valores como 0, se for o caso, basicamente o que estava fazendo era o seguinte.

```
select B.coluna
from A, B
where A.coluna = B.coluna(+) or B.coluna = 0;
```

Mas está retornando o seguinte, dizendo que não é possível fazer um left join num operador or.

outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN.

Poderiam me ajudar a dizer como eu posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

tenta:

```
select 
    B.coluna
from A
left outer join B on b.coluna = a.coluna or b.coluna = 0
```

tentando utilizar a mesma sintaxe que você utilizou, acho que ficaria assim:

```
select B.coluna
from A, B
where (A.coluna = B.coluna or B.coluna = 0)(+);
```